# PHP not catching sql error

Tags: php

I have a script to manage user login and when the username is in-putted into the field and the password is in-putted into it's field and they match to the db you log in if not you get an error returned parsed by the login form. however when you input an invalid value into the username (a username that doesn't exist) the code doesn't continue so how do I fix that??

```
<?php

require("bootstrap.php");

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER_SEC,DB_PASS_SEC) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME_SEC,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM username WHERE userName = '$_POST[username]'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!empty($_POST['username']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['userName']))
        {
            if(!empty($row['userPass']))
            {
                if($_POST['password'] === $row['userPass'])
                {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['logged']       = true;
                    $_SESSION['userName']     = $row['userName'];
                    $_SESSION['fname']        = $row['fname'];
                    $_SESSION['mname']        = $row['mname'];
                    $_SESSION['lname']        = $row['lname'];
                    $_SESSION['primnum']      = $row['primnum'];
                    $_SESSION['secnum']       = $row['secnum'];
                    $_SESSION['department']   = $row['department'];
                    $_SESSION['clearance']    = $row['clearance'];
                    $_SESSION['theme']        = $row['theme'];
                    $_SESSION['animations']   = $row['animations'];
                    $_SESSION['gtag']         = $row['gtag'];

                    header("Location: /workspace/index");
                }
                else
                {
                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION['logged']       = false;
                    $_SESSION['err']          = "0x001";

                    header("Location: /login");
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                session_start();

                $_SESSION['logged']       = false;
                $_SESSION['err']          = "0x005";

                header("Location: /login");
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            session_start();

            $_SESSION['logged']       = false;
            $_SESSION['err']          = "0x002";

            header("Location: /login");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['logged']       = false;
        $_SESSION['err']          = "0x003";

        header("Location: /login");
    }
}
else
{
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['logged']       = false;
    $_SESSION['err']          = "0x004";

    header("Location: /login");
}

?>
```

and yes I know about MySqli and PDO so **PLEASE DO NOT** Bring that Up.

Comment: past this code in your php to see errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: Why you write `session_start();` in every `else` condition. Why  not you write `session_start();` at the top of your page once.

Comment: my code was to be cleaned up later just need to fix the problem I code in segments this is the ugly rough draft

Comment: If you know about `mysqli` and `PDO` why aren't you using them? The `mysql` API __will be removed in the next release of PHP__. What then?

Comment: @HoboSapiens i will be converting my code when i have finished writing it (i'm not skilled enough with the new syntax) and just wanted to get the framework down that's all still mastering the new way of doing things

Comment: @shehary  
the only error it returns is `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\icebreaker\scripts\php\login.php on line 7` but the rest of my script works so that's not the problem

Comment: @HoboSapiens Then more money for the developers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line make the code stop

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

basically mysql_fetch_array($query) return false if there is no row to fetch.
so it will fall to die statement